# Basic relational algebra question

Tags: relational-theory

I'm new to this and have been given a database. I've been asked to write a Basic relational algebra formula which collects failed test results with a certain teacher and display the surname and code of the student.

```
STUDENT (StudentSurName, StudentCode)

TEACHER (TeacherName)

TEST (Result)

π StudentSurName,StudentCode (σ Result = "fail"(σ TeacherName = "Mr Willis"))
```

Can anyone help and point out where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
π StudentSurName,StudentCode (σ Result="fail" Test (σ TeacherName="Mr Willis" Teacher))
```

But even then it will not give a usable result since there is no relation between the `STUDENT`, `TEACHER`, and `TEST`. Who's result it is? Who gave the result?